# Mongodb self join add field before display (very difficult) also with java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Please help me in this complex mongodb query.
I have document records in a XYZ collection as:

```
{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c78dfdfdf,
    filename: "c78dfdfdf.xml"
  }
}

{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c7j9fdfdf,
    filename: "c7j9fdfdf.xml"
  }
}

{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c7j9fdfdf,
    filename: "c7j9fdfdf.gif"
  }
}

{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c7j9fdfdf,
    filename: "c7j9fdfdf.jpg"
  }
}
```

For some reason this structure cannot be changed.
Now I want to fire a query and get all the records with docid+".xml" as filename like 1st and 2nd record here and also it should append hasAttachment:"true" in all the results if any other document with same docid exists which contains filename as docid+any other extension otherwise hasAttachment:"false". For e.g. query should return as without update only select query:

```
{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c78dfdfdf,
    filename: "c78dfdfdf.xml"
  },
  hasAttachment:"false"
}

{ key1:value1,
  key2:value2,
  key3:{
    docid:c7j9fdfdf,
    filename: "c7j9fdfdf.xml"
  },
  hasAttachment:"true"
}
```

I need both query and mongo-java-driver code to perform same operation.

First I want to query all the documents where filename=docid+".xml" and then i want to add hasAttachment=true/false by checking whether docid+non xml extension exists .
Thanks
Nitin

Comment: Could you please add what you've tried already so we can more efficiently help?

Comment: it requires aggregation framework in which i am a beginner,i am able to query like db.XYZ.find({$where:function(){if(this.key3.fileName==this.key3.docid+".xml")return false;else return true;}}).pretty()        this is giving me those documents where filename extension is not xml

Comment: But i want to run that inside a loop like foreach/aggregation for all the .xml extension filename and add a field hasAttachment=true if any other extension filename exists for same docid before returning result

Comment: There are no "stored procedures" in MongoDB and this sounds like it will need to be done in steps (fetch matches, update matches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be pretty easily done with [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/):

```
db.runCommand({
  mapreduce: '<% YOUR COLLECTION NAME %>',
  map: function() {
    var id = this.key3.docid;
    if (this.key3.filename === (id + '.xml')) {
      emit(id, {doc: this});
    } else {
      emit(id, {attach: true});
    }
  },
  reduce: function(key, vals) {
    return vals.reduce(function(o1, o2) {
      return {
        doc: o1.doc || o2.doc,
        attach: o1.attach || o2.attach
      };
    });
  },
  finalize: function(key, val) {
    val.doc.hasAttachment = !!val.attach;
    return val.doc;
  },
  out: {inline: 1}
})
```

Comment: you solved my problem,made my day,it is working....A little more help on getting it done via mongo java driver is required...

Comment: You can use MapReduce method of [DBCollection object](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html).

Comment: One more question, if there are millions of records and i want to put a limit, then it will do these operations on limited set or it will emit all keys and then before returning result it will limit records?  Because on applying limit to mapreduce, docid should check attachments from all the records, thats all i want....

Comment: Unfortunately, it'll limit the number of documents to run mapreduce on. But if you may sort you documents by `'key3.docid'` first, so you won't get more the one wrong document. Alternative solution is to MapReduce the whole collection into another temporary collection and then query it with limit.